# Javascript 'while' loop, how to stop iteration if condition is going to be false

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am practicing while loop and below is code

```
PHONE_PRICE = 90; 
bank_balance = 303.91; 
amount = 0;
while (amount < bank_balance) {    
  amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE;
}
console.log("Your purchase: " + amount);
```

Now I understand after each iteration it is checking the condition and running the next iteration. I am trying to stop the next iteration if condition is going to be false. I have tried with do while loop as well however it gives the same behavior.

Here I am not trying to loop thru an array.... however trying to stop the iteration if condition is going to be false. Let me know if its same as loop thru an array in anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I recommend you creating new variables using the `var` keyword, and not just assigning them like you're doing here. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is a link if you're interested.

Comment: Took note of that @FredrikA. Thanks

Comment: If you want to do the addition a bit more terse, you could also use the `+=` operator. With that, you could write `amount += PHONE_PRICE` instead of `amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to stop the next iteration if condition is going to be
>   false

If you want to only increase the amount if it won't exceeed the balance, then try

```
while ((amount + PHONE_PRICE) < bank_balance) {    
  amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE;
}
```

This will ensure that amount won't exceed 270 (3 iterations of 90).

Comment: Either this, or you could simply do the incremenation and if-statement in the loop. `amount += PHONE_PRICE;` and `if (... > ...) break;`.